# Can you temporarily go over 200 dwellers with unique dwellers from lunchbox rewards?

Tags: fallout-shelter

It seems that you can temporarily go past your storage space limit with weapons and outfits from lunchboxes.

Right now I have 200 dwellers and 2 lunchboxes. Can I get a unique dweller from the lunchboxes right now and temporarily go over the 200 limit, or should I kill off some of my current dwellers before opening the lunchboxes?

Comment: I think you are in the unique position to tell us. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**At 200 dwellers:**

- Radio station and dwellers stop showing up unless you find one in a lunchbox, it will stay outside until you kill someone so he/she can go in, or stay outside forever.
- Your radio stations stop flashing, they still get happiness buff but they don't bring in new dwellers
- Random people from the wastes won't show up.
- Pregnant dwellers stay pregnant (Not sure for update 1.03).

Comment: Oh, that's right! At population cap, you can't invite new dwellers inside, and dwellers from lunchboxes show up outside the vault door by default. +1

Comment: The line outside your vault will only hold 10 dwellers, after that the game will prevent you from opening any more lunchboxes until you free up waiting line space.